# Populating Repeater with disabled ViewState (asp.net/vb.net)

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have some code bellow :

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(....
 If Not IsPostBack Then 
   Session("isloaded") = True
   PopulateData()
 End If
 If Session("isloaded") = True Then Session("isloaded") = False Else PopulateData()
End Sub

Private Sub btnEditCancel_Click(....
 Session("isloaded") = False
End Sub

Private Sub btnEditSave_Click(...
 Session("isloaded") = True
 PopulateData()
End Sub
```

Because, when I click `btnEditSave` `Repeater` is populated. But, when I click `btnEditCancel` `Repeater` isn't populated. `PopulateData()` is subroutine for populating `asp:Repeater` using `asp:SqlDataSource`.
btw. `EnableViewState` in `asp:Repeater` is disabled.

How to solve this problem?

Is it possible that `Page_Load` fire first and after that `Session("isloaded")` is set to `False`?

p.s. sorry for my weak english, I hope you, people, will understand point of question.

Comment: But why didn't you called `PopulateData()` inside `btnEditCancel_Click`

Comment: Isn't enough to set `Session("isloaded") = False` and `Page_Load` will call `PopulateData()` ?

Answer (score 1):

First in your code in the `btnEditSave_Click` event you are making  `Session("isloaded") = True` then if you click `btnEditCancel` button in the `Page load` because its `Postback`
it will execute only

```
 If Session("isloaded") = True Then Session("isloaded") = False Else PopulateData()
```

in that it will only execute `IF` part as you are making `Session("isloaded") = True` in 
`btnEditSave_Click` event it will not call `PopulateData()` in `ELSE` part

Make a Change in `btnEditCancel_Click` event like

```
Private Sub btnEditCancel_Click(....
 If Session("isloaded") = False Then PopulateData()
End Sub
```

Comment: uuups, my bad... sorry... problem is, when I click `btnEditCancel` `Repeater` will not populate. I forgot to complete that line in `Page_Load`... post edited.

Comment: I use Your first suggestion. On that way I avoid using that session. Thx... Also, I put wrong value for `Session("isloaded")` in `If Not IsPostBack` block... :-/